# mysql between operator with dates

Tags: mysql, date, between

```
select '2011-02-29' BETWEEN '2011-02-01' AND '2011-03-03'‎
```

this is returning 1. I think **between** doesn't consider leap year. I want your view on this?

**[EDIT]**
`SELECT DATE( '2010-04-31' )` is returning NULL;
But `select str_to_date('2010-04-31', '%Y-%m-%d')` is retuning date.

Why?

Thanks
Venu

Comment: i think its implementation choice? str_to_date just not check...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to cast it to date like:

```
SELECT DATE('2011-02-29') BETWEEN DATE('2011-02-01') AND DATE('2011-03-03')
```

from the site :

> For best results when using BETWEEN with date or time values, use
>   CAST() to explicitly convert the values to the desired data type.
>   Examples: If you compare a DATETIME to two DATE values, convert the
>   DATE values to DATETIME values. If you use a string constant such as
>   '2001-1-1' in a comparison to a DATE, **cast the string to a DATE**.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is you're comparing strings, not dates.
If you try:

```
select DATE('2011-02-29') you get a NULL...
```

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing strings ... you have to cast the values (or at least the first one) to DATE

Use this:

```
 SELECT DATE('2011-02-29') BETWEEN '2011-02-01' AND '2011-03-03'
```

This will give you NULL because the **date is not real**.

```
 SELECT DATE('2008-02-29') BETWEEN '2008-02-01' AND '2008-03-03'
```

This will give you 1 (TRUE) because the **date is real** (leap year)

Answer (score 1):

`DATE` checks the validity while `str_to_date` does not.

```
mysql> select str_to_date('2010-02-31', '%Y-%m-%d');
+---------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('2010-02-31', '%Y-%m-%d') |
+---------------------------------------+
| 2010-02-31                            |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select str_to_date('2010-04-31', '%Y-%m-%d');
+---------------------------------------+
| str_to_date('2010-04-31', '%Y-%m-%d') |
+---------------------------------------+
| 2010-04-31                            |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> select date('2010-02-31');
+--------------------+
| date('2010-02-31') |
+--------------------+
| NULL               |
+--------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> select date('2010-04-31');
+--------------------+
| date('2010-04-31') |
+--------------------+
| NULL               |
+--------------------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

**UPDATE** according to @Aziz , `DATE` will check whether a date is real or not. According to my test, seems `str_to_date` does not check.

Comment: SELECT DATE(  '2010-04-31' ) is returning NULL;  But select str_to_date('2010-04-31', '%Y-%m-%d') is retuning date..