# CAST on where clause performance. Should we cast datetime string input?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, casting, where-clause

Should we use **`CAST`** for compare a date like on query below?

On this discussion [mysql between operator with dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8076236/mysql-between-operator-with-dates) said it's better to convert your parameter STRING to DATE, but isn't mysql function in WHERE clause will make performance slower?

```
SELECT * from tableA WHERE datetimecolumn = CAST('2014-10-12' AS DATE)
```

Comment: yeah... always compare datetime to datetimes.  dates and datetimes are not strings.  they're special creatures.

Answer (score 0):

use it this way:

```
SELECT  * 
from    tableA 
WHERE   datetimecolumn =  STR_TO_DATE('2014-10-12', '%Y-%m-%d');
```

documentation... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

okay.. so here's why.

```
mysql> select * from temp;
+---------------------+
| dt                  |
+---------------------+ 
| 2014-10-11 23:30:53 |
+---------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

you could also do it this way... but you need a function.  it won't hurt.

```
SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(startTime, "%Y-%m-%d") = '2010-04-29'

SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE DATE(startTime) = '2010-04-29'
```

from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2758585/623952

this is what i ended up with... so I guess, if you know your exact datetime. use it.

```
mysql> select count(*) from temp;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|   399998 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.11 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from temp where temp_dt = date('2014-10-17');
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        3 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.15 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from temp where date_format(temp_dt, "%Y-%m-%d") = '2014-10-17';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|    57590 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.17 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from temp where substring(temp_dt,0,10) = '2014-10-17';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.14 sec)

mysql> select count(*) from temp where temp_dt = '2014-10-17 17:06:20';
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        9 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.12 sec)
```