# Select a random date between two other dates SQL

Tags: mysql

I need to select a number of records in MySQL between two dates randomly.

For example select 4 records between 30, between 2020-01-01, and 2020-06-01 randomly

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: share input vs expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order any result set randomly by using the `RAND()` function:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE date BETWEEN "2020-01-01" AND "2020-06-01" 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 4
```

Comment: why did u cast the date?

Comment: @Shoaeb The variant without `CAST` will not check if a date is actually valid. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/8076236/3340665 and https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=84cdc0c9c0e1b75356b0ed7d5425e889 for examples.